# Is there a way to extract duplicate lines in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text-3, deduplication

I need to perform 2 operations in Sublime Text: extract unique lines and extract duplicate lines. For example for input

```
a
b
a
```

Extract duplicates should result in:

```
a
```

and Extract unique should result in:

```
b
```

Is there a built-in operation or a plugin to do that?

Answer (score 56):

You can find duplicate lines easily by running a `Sort Lines` then searching for this regex that uses line boundary markers `^` and `$` and the back reference `\1`.

```
^(.+)$\n^\1$
```

Follow that with a Find All, Copy, Paste in a new tab, Permute Lines | Unique and you've extracted them.

Comment: This is amazing: I added a small addition that helped me: 
1. Run the regex
2. Replace all the matched values with: \t$1, which will indent all the matched values and keep only 1 instance of them in the file
3. Run another regex: ^\d.*$ and replace the \d with your relevant tag
4. This will keep only the duplicated values

Comment: Great and elegant regex solution. TBH I was looking for a Sublime Package to do this. But this simple search was simpler and enough for my needs. Thank you.

Comment: Purely genius...

Comment: I sometimes forget to "think outside the box".

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately I don't have access to Sublime Text at the moment, so I'm not able to test this, but I believe something like the following might work for you:

1. Sort the lines via the `Edit -> Sort Lines` command
2. Install the [Highlight Duplicates](https://github.com/qur2/HighlightDuplicates) plugin, and use it to highlight all the duplicate lines
3. Cut the highlighted lines to the Clipboard, and paste them into a New File
4. The lines that remain in the original file are your **Extract Unique** lines
5. In the New File, select all the text, and remove duplicate lines via the `Edit -> Permute Lines -> Unique` command
6. The lines that remain in the New File are your **Extract Duplicates** lines

I'm not entirely sure that step #1 is actually necessary, but I included it just in case.

Comment: I wondered the same thing and just tried it (Sublime 3.0, here)... sorting first is not necessary.  (Unlike with Unix 'uniq'.)  Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem (show me the dupes)... didn't find an easy Sublime-based answer and fell back to using Unix commands (my file had the data I wanted to find the duplicates of in columns 11-56):

```
cut -c 11-56 myfile.dat | sort | uniq -d
```

Posted here as an FYI to others.

Comment: by the way I'va made a [plugin that does that](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Extract%20Lines)

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way to do this with Sublime Text was to just sort lines (f5 on mac), permute lines > unique, then view the diff with git.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified @MJH answer above to get duplicated lines with Sublime 3 and DiffMerge, without using `Highlight Duplicates` plugin.

1. Sort the lines via Sublime 3 `Edit -> Sort Lines` command
2. Save original file as *sorted_orig.txt*
3. Select all the text, and remove duplicate lines via Sublime 3 `Edit -> Permute Lines -> Unique` command
4. Save modified file as *no_dup_sorted.txt*
5. Start diff with DiffMerge tool with *sorted_orig.txt* and *no_dup_sorted.txt* files.
6. Use `Export -> File Diffs` in DiffMerge to get a list of duplicates in clipboard or save to another file.